# Moving audio question to Sound Design instead of closing it

Tags: discussion

With all respect I think [Tim Post](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/3696/tim-post) did a very lazy job [closing this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9586/320-kbps-mp3-laptop-sound-card-studio-headphones-what-is-the-bottleneck) instead of moving it to https://sound.stackexchange.com/ after audio and video split apart. Can someone please fix it?

Comment: It wasn't lazy, questions were pretty closely examined. This simply would not have fared well on SD (there were a dozen or so similar questions that ultimately just landed in closed territory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post was in fact specifically discussed. It appears to be a consumer issue that is not content creation related.  If that's the case, then it is off topic on both sites.  If you feel that it isn't about a consumer issue, then it may be worth re-opening and migrating, however I strongly expect it would be rapidly closed on SD as off topic.